# Modify regular expression for verify that password has at least one uppercase letter. Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this regular expresion

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{6,30}$/
```

I want modify it for verify that password has at least one uppercase letter

I tried put one + sign after the A-Z+ , but it not worked

```
 /^[A-Z+a-z0-9_-]{6,30}$/
```

Can you help me , please?

Comment: That plus sign would just allow you to put a plus sign in your password... you need to use lookaheads for something like this.

Comment: I'd change that `6` instead ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])[\w-]{6,30}$/
```

Here `(?=.*?[A-Z])` is a positive lookahead that makes sure your regex has at least one upper case English letter.
Also note that `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: Thanks anubhava . the - character is not included in \w ?

Comment: No hyphen is not considered a word character that's why I had it separate above.

Comment: Anubhava How I do that the regular expression have at least 2 uppercase letter instead of one

Comment: For that you can use: `/^(?=(.*?[A-Z]){2})[\w-]{6,30}$/`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I'm really bad at regex lookahead, but I would like to provide another solution here, which is a **one-liner**:

```
# Data:
passwords = %w(
  tlkjadfjklk
  asdfkjlaj3223$%^&*
  kljjkl32jklfa%^
  ABCDLK233223
  Aiou34i^&*
  23fsaAiou34i^&*
  kljasf90843klj3()*Dlkjafa323
  klAjasf90843klj3()*Dlkjafa323
  A
  ABCDEF
  klAjasf90843klj3klAjasf90843klj3klAjasf90843klj3)

# Code:
passwords.each{|pwd| p [/^(.*?[A-Z]+)/, /[A-Z]+(.*?)$/].inject(0){|sum, regex| sum += regex.match(pwd) ? $~[1].size : 0}.between?(6, 30)}

# Results:
false
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
false
true
false
```

To make it a bit clear, please find below expanded version of the one-liner:

```
regex_begin = /^(.*?[A-Z]+)/
regex_after = /[A-Z]+(.*?)$/
passwords.each do |pwd|
  len = [regex_begin, regex_after].inject(0) do |sum, regex|
    sum += regex.match(pwd) ? $~[1].size : 0
  end
  p len.between?(6, 30)
end
```